# Foreach in a pictures name array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of pictures:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "./images/00.jpg" [1]=> string(18) "./images/green.png" [2]=> string(18) "./images/image.png" } string(27) "./images/03/./images/00.jpg"
```

The number of pictures and of course the names will vary at any time, as there will be constant deleted/added new pictures.

And I use this foreach to loop on all the names:

```
foreach($images as $image){
            $dest = $dest."/".$image;
            copy($image, $dest);
            unlink($image);
        }
```

in the $images var I store my images names array (listed above).

and in the $dest I have:

```
$dest = "./images/".$month;
$month = date("m");
```

The $image var is taking good  values (taking each picture one by one full path ex: ./images/00.jpg), but problem is with my $dest var I will get

```
./images/03/./images/00.jpg       //first iteration
./images/03/./images/00.jpg/./images/green.png     //second iteration
./images/03/./images/00.jpg/./images/green.png/./images/image.png  //third
```

What I want to do is to get in the $dest only the:

```
 ./images/03/00.jpg 
 ./images/03/green.png
 ./images/03/image.png
```

1 value/ iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinitialize your $dest variable in each iteration.

This should work :

```
foreach($images as $image){
        $dest = "./images/".$month."/".substr($image,strlen("./images/"));
        copy($image, $dest);
        unlink($image);
    }
```

**Update :** 
Use substr on your $image var to get only the part of the string that you are interested in. See the [doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php) for more informations.

Comment: With that I will get ./images/03/./images/00.jpg and ./images/03/./images/green.png and ./images/03/./images/image.png, and don't need the second ./images argument, there is a way to destroy it ? Look on my desired $dest output.

Answer (score 1):

`$dest = $dest."/".$image;`

In above statement it will work first time fine next time its not initialising `$dest` variable again it will take the previous value.

So, you can do the same in other way like below.

```
foreach($images as $image){
            $img_name = explode('/', $image);
            $dest = "./images/". date("m") ."/".$img_name[2]; // ./images/03/00.jpg
            copy($image, $dest);
            unlink($image);
        }
```

Comment: With that I will get ./images/03/./images/00.jpg and ./images/03/./images/green.png and ./images/03/./images/image.png, and don't need the second ./images argument, there is a way to destroy it ? Look on my desired $dest output.

Comment: @TatuBogdan Edited my answer... please check

Answer (score 1):

Why did you concate **$dest** variable .That is what it's return that the following result

```
./images/03/./images/00.jpg       //first iteration
./images/03/./images/00.jpg/./images/green.png     //second iteration
./images/03/./images/00.jpg/./images/green.png/./images/image.png  //third
```

You can use `pathinfo()` function to do what you want . Have a look below...

```
$month=date('m');
foreach($images as $image){
      $image_details=pathinfo($image);//The pathinfo() function returns an array that contains information about a path.
      $dest = $image_details['dirname']."/".$month."/".$image_details['basename'];
      copy($image, $dest);
      unlink($image);
    }
```